# Issue: .perform() method throwing MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Exception in Robotframework

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

For `.perform()` method of `ActionChains` class we are facing exception “`MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException`: Message: move target out of bounds” frequently in application. Majorly found for mouse actions and click at coordinate on canvas element.
Scrolling we already tried and element is center of the screen still issue is observed

we are using `robotframework==3.1, robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.3.0, chrome=83.0.4103.61, chromedriver=83.0.4103.14`